# How to add a unique horizontal bar marker in Bar Chart for each group

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization, markers

I want to create the graph bellow, but I want to add a horizontal line marker to each group as shown bellow, do you know how to add it based on the code I currently have? 
[image]

```
data = np.array([
[5,   3,  2 ],
[2,  -3,  5 ],
[ -4, 4, -6],
[-5, -3, -1],
[2,   6,   6]     
])
bar_markers = np.array([4, 3, -2, 2, -1])
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(len(data[:, 0]))
width = 0.25
p1 = plt.bar(index, data[:,0], width, bottom = 0, color = 'yellowgreen')
p2 = plt.bar(index+width, data[:, 1], width, bottom = 0, color = 'purple')
p3 = plt.bar(index+2*width, data[:, 2], width, bottom = 0, color = 'pink')
axs.set_xticks(index + width / 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can "cheat" and make the height of each bar 0 but start the bottom of each bar at a different height, i.e. do this:

```
p4 = plt.bar(index+width, [0]*len(bar_markers), width*3, bottom=bar_markers, edgecolor='k')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you know any way to adjust the thickness of this blue bar? I just realize that it looks good when I have few samples, but it becomes extremely thin when the sample size becomes huge.

Comment: @Jason I would try adding the `linewidth` keyword argument and tinkering with the value. If that doesn't get you what you want, you can always make the bars "thicker" by making them taller then adjust their bottom to center them properly.